# Forcefully call viewdidload after poptorootviewcontroller

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, memory-management

I am working on a project in which I am playing and doing some animation in `rootview` controller.

Now when I push to another view from `rootview` and `setting new animation start point` then when i `poptorootview` then animation does not start from the new point as `viewdidload is not called.`

And if i forcefully call `viewdidload` in `viewwillapear` method the app crashes as o`bjects are already released`.

Also I have to `check new start point` specifically in `viewdidload` only.

How can i avoid this?

Thanks

Comment: why don't do perform all the task in viewwillapear  that you are performing in viewDidLoad on "poptorootview"??

Comment: Side note: backticks are only for `code` and not for every keyword in the text. Using `backticks` for `any` important `word` does `not` increase `the` legibility.

Answer (score 1):

You can't forcefully call *viewDidLoad* anywhere throughout the lifecycle of your view controller. It is a controlled call.

If you want to perform any specific work after view switching you can either code in *viewWillAppear* and/or *viewDidAppear*. If you want to show animations use *viewDidAppear*.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually force the `viewDidLoad` to be called using:

```
__unused UIView *aView = myViewController.view;
```

This is a common practice for testing, for example.